# How do you setup the Irrlicht and Bullet engines for Android development?

Tags: bullet-physics, irrlicht

I have begun researching graphics and physics engines to use for an Android 3d game that I would like to make.

While researching I stumbled across this [page](http://renzhi.ca/2011/05/19/programming-3d-games-on-android-with-irrlicht-and-bullet-part-1/) where he talks about how you can use the Irrlicht graphics engine and the Bullet physics engine for Android development.

I have a few questions about this

1. Will these engines work for Android like he says?
2. Are these good choices for open source engines on Android?
3. What does he meen when he says, "Then we put all the C/C++ source codes under the jni folder". What is the jni folder? Should this go under the src folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, I don't see why not
2. They're OK. But my engine of choice at the moment is [libgdx](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1500) It has the Box2D physics engine integrated
3. Please look up the [documentation of the Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) In short, there needs to be a jni directory in your Android project that creates a native C++ library that can be used from your Java code. You can refer to the samples in the NDK to setup your project.

Comment: Why do you think libgdx is a better choice?

Comment: Much more active community, active development going on for Android, everything is well integrated and there are a lot of examples.

Comment: Just beware, libGDX seriously lacks in documentation. It makes up for it with testing and an active community.